# Tomcat startup speed up by skipping scanning jars, if I skip all jars, why didn't throw a ClassNotFound exception?

Tags: java, tomcat, jar, tomcat7

I want to speed up Tomcat startup skipping scanning jars, but there are lots of jars, that I can't figure one by one, so I want to skip all jars, but I am not sure what will happen, is a classNotFound exception, or a much more slow start-up?

I add configuration as below into catalina.properties, and my project still speed up by 10 seconds without error. So I want to know why it didn't throw a ClassNotFound exception.
```

```
tomcat.util.scan.DefaultJarScanner.jarsToSkip=*.jar
org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.jarsToSkip=*.jar
org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.jarsToSkip=*.jar
```

```

Comment: What did it happend if skip all jars, which contains some useful ones.

Comment: take tld jars for a example, there a 500 jars that didn't contain any tld files, 2 jars that contains tld files: `jersey-server-1.9.jar`, `spring-webmvc-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are skipping services that tomcat can provide, not loading of the classes (which is handled by the classloader). These services look for configuration, annotations (and/or other metadata), to configure *context* and (from [`TldConfig`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/startup/TldConfig.html)) *Startup event listener for a Context that configures application listeners configured in any TLD files.*

Comment: Do you mean it support to throw exceptions if I skip scanning all jars? But in my project, it didn't happen, and it is still ok to open web pages.

Comment: No, it didn't load TLD config files from your jars.

Comment: you are right, and now I know why it didn't throw any exception, for that my project didn't use any tld files from my jars and also others.